# Why won't Android Studio recognize the setShareContent() method for my ShareButton when trying to use Facebook SDK?

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk, sharing

I'm learning how to implement a button that I can use to have users share content from my Android app to their Facebook timeline. Using a mixture of tutorials and the Facebook Developer website. This is the class that I'm using but for some reason I'm getting an error of 'cannot resolve symbol setShareContent' even though this part is copied from the Facebook developer tutorial. What have I missed? I feel like there must be a missing import but I can't see what :/

```
package com.example.androidfacebooksharelinktutorial;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.share.model.ShareLinkContent;
import com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    // Model the Facebook content to be shared
    ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
            .setQuote("Connect on a global scale.")
            .build();
    ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton)findViewById(R.id.share_btn);
    shareButton.setShareContent(content);

}
```

Comment: please add a link to the official tutorial. what´s that "setQuote" part? are you trying to prefill the message?

Comment: I'm following along here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android and have also been looking at: https://tutorialwing.com/share-link-using-latest-android-facebook-sdk/ ultimately I want to model 'quote' sharing with a link as per the Facebook tutorial. I'm trying to model the content then create the sharing button.